# Recommended framework for java web services

Tags: java, web-services, frameworks

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289977/recommended-framework-for-java-web-services) was asked about 18 months back. Wanted to see if the community still agrees with CXF as a good choice for the question posted.

Looking for a good framework, if we go the schema-first route.

Thank you.

Comment: The big caveat for that last answer was "if you are using java-first". This makes a huge difference to the choice of "best framework". Do you want to do java-first, or schema-first?

Comment: The policy seems to be schema-first.

Answer (score 1):

I use JAX-WS: 
https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/

Based on annotations, easy to get started. Heaps od examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Axis2 1.5.1 and it sucks. The documentation is very very poor. I feel almost on my own when have to implement jms transport with signing and encryption. A simple client always requires an Axis2 repository in file system.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would recommend JAX-WS as Leonardo suggested. It complies with the current specifications. 
I used CXF in the past and never had any issues with it (to the extent of my needs). Of course one can argue if Metro (https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) framework is superior over CXF. In my opinion you should try both and decide which you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use REST with JAX-RS if you have the choice.